# Nightwatch call to selenium elementIdElement seems slow

Tags: javascript, performance, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Within my nightwatch top-level test, I use the selenium "elements" call to record the set of DOM elements matching a certain class, then subsequently parse through that list with nightwatch perform() callback to identify those elements that also match another class using elementIdElement. For example

```
module.exports = { 
    function(client)
    {
        var elems = []
        client.elements('class name','autoselect', function(elements)
        {   if (elements.status == 0)
               elems = elements.value
            else
               exit(-1)
        })
        var witness = []
        client.perform(function(client,done)
        {   for (var elem in elems) 
            {   var element = elems[elem].ELEMENT
                client.elementIdElement(element,'class name', 'witness',
                function(result)
                {   witness.push(result.status != -1)
                })
            }
            done()
        })
        client.pause(2000)
        client.end()
    }
}
```

What I'm finding is that the elementIdElement callbacks are executing slowly, on the order of 1 second each. All the other selenium callbacks execute quickly, e.g., elementIdAttribute, so I'm wondering if this is normal performance behavior or is there some way to improve performance.

Comment: Further clarification... elementIdElement is significantly faster when if finds the 'class name', but slow when it doesn't. Nightwatch docs say elementIdElement searches for elements "starting from the identified element". Does this mean it's starting from that point through the rest of the DOM, or only through that element's dependents? I think it's the latter, but that being the case, it shouldn't take so long.

Comment: You can set the amount of time to wait for a timeout with the `timeoutsImplicitWait` command. See also: http://nightwatchjs.org/api#timeoutsImplicitWait